# Which ISO 8583 message type required for PIN Verification?

Tags: iso8583

I would like to send a request to a Credit Card System to confirm if PIN is correct for a card.

I have an idea on 
- How ISO 8583 messages are formatted and bitmap is populated. 
- How to send an ISO8583 1100 to authorize my transaction request. 
- How to send an ISO8583 1200 , to do actual transaction.

However I can't find ISO8583 message XXXX which I can use only to just verify PIN.

Answer (score 1):

You should use message type 1100 and appropriate processing code (DE03). It’s depend on your host implementation, but in base ISO specification is for this purpose processing code “710000”.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for precisely. MTI 1100. Looks it does pot more than just authorisation of transaction. I am learning that 1100 could be used for balance enquiry , card registration, transition posting sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You include data element 52 (and eventually 53 if you're using DUKPT) as part of your authorisation/financial message.